# Stop FLV Audio in Video Gallery

Tags: jquery, flv

I'm trying to create a video gallery of sorts and I'm having an issue with the audio on .FLVs still playing in the background when I use jQuery to slide to a new Video.

Is there any sort of way to force the audio of a .FLV to stop via jQuery, javascript etc.?

Here is how I'm loading the .FLV:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="300" height="240" id="FLVPlayer">
<param name="movie" value="/wp-content/themes/blank-theme/flash/FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="scale" value="noscale" />
<param name="salign" value="lt" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="&amp;MM_ComponentVersion=1&amp;skinName=/wp-content/themes/blank-theme/flash/Clear_Skin_2&amp;streamName=".( $formattedURL )."&amp;autoPlay=false&amp;autoRewind=false" />
<param name="swfversion" value="8,0,0,0" />
<!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don't want users to see the prompt. -->
<param name="expressinstall" value="/wp-content/themes/blank-theme/flash/expressInstall.swf" />
<!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/wp-content/themes/blank-theme/flash/FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" width="300" height="240">
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
  <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
  <param name="salign" value="lt" />
  <param name="FlashVars" value="&amp;MM_ComponentVersion=1&amp;skinName=/wp-content/themes/blank-theme/flash/Clear_Skin_2&amp;streamName=".( $formattedURL )."&amp;autoPlay=false&amp;autoRewind=false" />
  <param name="swfversion" value="8,0,0,0" />
  <param name="expressinstall" value="/wp-content/themes/blank-theme/flash/expressInstall.swf" />
  <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
  <div>
    <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
    <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="/wp-content/themes/blank-theme/images/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
  </div>
  <!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

With $formattedURL being the link to my .flv.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks is advance

**UPDATE**

Ok so I've figured out how I can remove the audio, however, the method I've used doesn't work in IE7/8 :S (it appears that my .FLV won't load into the box)

I'm cloning the video div and appending it to a div when a link is clicked, see the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){

     $('div.video2').hide();
     var clone1 = $("div.video1 div.videoInner").clone(true);
     var clone2 = $("div.video2 div.videoInner").clone(true);
     $("div.video1 div.videoInner").remove();                
     $("div.video2 div.videoInner").remove();

     $('a.vid1').click(function() {

        $('div.video1').slideDown();
        $('div.video2').slideUp();

        $(clone1).appendTo('div.video1');
     });
      $('a.vid2').click(function() {

        $('div.video1').slideUp();
        $('div.video2').slideDown();

        $(clone2).appendTo('div.video2');
     });
});</script>
```

Where a.vid1 and a.vid2 are the links I'm using to switch between the two videos.

Any thoughts?